# UILabel Not Populated From Array When Button Pressed

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have a `UITableViewController` with  custom `UITableViewCells` which contain a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`. 

The problem is that the `UILabel` which is initially set to 0, is not changing when the button is pressed which changes its particular value in the array. When I use `println()` the actual array has been changed, but the `UILabel` has not.

The following is the code from my `UITableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let groupChatCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupChatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as textCell

    groupChatCell.voteScoreLabel.text="\(groupVote[indexPath.row])"
    groupChatCell.voteScoreLabel.tag=indexPath.row

    return groupChatCell
}
```

`voteScoreLabel` is the `UILabel` which I want to update from the array.
`groupVote` is the `array` that is meant to populate the label with the scores. I set the `UILabel` tag equal to its index path so that I can then reference it when I need to pick out a particular value of the array.

The following is from my custom `UITableViewCellController`:

```
@IBAction func upVoteButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]=groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]+1
}
```

What am I doing wrong here so that I can make the `UILabel` change when its corresponding value in the array has changed.

Comment: Did you **call**  `instance_of_your_tableView.reloadData()` ?

Comment: @ko100v.d I did try that in the `viewWillApear` method.

Comment: `@IBAction func upVoteButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]=groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]+1
    // reload your tableView data here after you click on a certen button
}`

Comment: @ko100v.d Alright that works. If you want to put an answer, and I would accept that would be great for future viewers. Thanks

Comment: Already done, thanks for the advice, i'm new here :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the your tableView data when a button is clicked.
The reloadData() function calls every tableView delegate/data source method again and reload the whole controller if its UITableViewController or the whole tableView if its a view added to another controller

> Your code should look like this:

```
@IBAction func upVoteButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
   groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]=groupVote[voteScoreLabel.tag]+1
   instance_of_your_tableView.reloadData()
   // If this is the name of method in swift //
}
```

Regards

Comment: I actually had to use NSNotificationCenter, because when I did the instance way, I got the error that the instance does not contain a member named reloadData(). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well if you use a UITableViewController you should probably use

`self.reloadData` :)

Comment: The IBAction was in a different ViewController.

Comment: O, my mistake, did you find a solution, or i should write another answer? :)

Comment: You could write a solution using the NSNotification center. Otherwise, I will.